# iphone pushviewcontroller to landscape

Tags: iphone, landscape, pushviewcontroller

I've simple iphone application. it has 3 views. first view is portrait view that has 3 buttons. second view has a table view which is also a portrait. In first view, on click of a button second view is shown. on click of a cell in second view, thrid view is shown. but third view is a landscape.
I'm using "pushViewController" to navigate from each view.
When creating views in IB, first two views are portait and 3rd view is a landscape. In 3rd viewcontroller, i'm using following code as well:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
//return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft));
```

}

How can I show first two views in portrait and third view in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in viewDidLoad

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a collection of links to related issues in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953351/iphone-landscape-faq-and-solutions). In particular, check out the answer of pix0r [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891395/landscape-only-iphone-app-with-multiple-nibs).